# Django get foreign key object inside Queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    cur_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC), blank=True, null=True)
    week_no = models.IntegerField()
    day_no = models.IntegerField()

class SubEvent(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.IntegerField()

class SubSubEvent(models.Model):
    sub_event = models.ForeignKey(SubEvent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    length = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get a Queryset from `SubSubEvent` model, which includes all the Foreign keys as one single object. What I have now is:

```
querySet = SubSubEvent.objects.filter(sub_event__event__cur_datetime__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

This will return a queryset, and using a for loop to get `__dict__` on each of objects, I get something like this:

```
{'event_id': 1, '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fd7d9cefeb8>, 'id': 10, 'length': '1'}
```

This is just a part of the query I want to achieve. What I really want, is all the fields in `event_id` instead of just the `id` number. In other word, all the fields (including data) from `Event` plus `SubEvent` plus `SubSubEvent` in one queryset. This queryset should contains objects with cur_datetime, week_no, day_no, version and length.

Comment: I am not sure to understand: your query gives you `SubSubEvent` instances, from which you can access related `SubEvent` and `Event` instances, and then all their attributes (e.g. `querySet.first().sub_event.event.cur_datetime`, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

```
qs = SubSubEvent.objects \
    .select_related('sub_event__event') \
    .filter(sub_event__event__cur_datetime__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

You can then access the related `SubEvent` and `Event` resources without hitting the database.

```
sub_sub_event = qs[0]
sub_event = sub_sub_event.sub_event    # doesn't hit the database
event = sub_sub_event.sub_event.event  # doesn't hit the database
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working as it should. I just thought maybe there is a way that the `qs` includes all of the fileds for the `event` and `sub_event` as a single variable. For example, is it possible that `sub_sub_event = qs[0]` returns all the fields, including fields from foreign keys? (in this case we can skip `sub_event = sub_sub_event.sub_event` and `sub_event = sub_sub_event.sub_event`)

Comment: You may be interested in [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).